# Is it generally possible to determine how long it takes for a system to reach its stationary state, without simulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, complex-systems

Let's say I'm dealing with the heat equation with some initial and boundary conditions, for example example our system can be a $1 \times 1$ metallic plate. Assuming that the initial temperature distribution simply diffuses and there is no energy input, the system will eventually reach a stationary solution. But is it possible to analytically determine how long it takes to reach this equilibrium, or is it simply something one must determine numerically?

Comment: This is the sort of problem that Fourier invented Fourier analysis for.

Comment: @JohnDoty Can you expand on that?

Comment: @agaminon look up solutions to the  Fourier Heat  equation.

Comment: Technically it takes forever. But this is what a diffusivity length is good for.

Comment: The way of answering this is to show how to calculate the time constant of the lowest frequency Fourier mode for the domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you solve the heat equation $$u'_t =  u''_{xx}+u''_{yy}+\ldots$$ with separation of variables as $u=X(\mathbf{x})T(t)$ you get $XT' = (X''_{xx}+X''_{yy}+\ldots)T$ and hence the $T'/T = (X''_{xx}+X''_{yy}+\ldots)/X = k$ for some constant $k$. So the equation for the time dependent part will be $T'-kT=0$ which has solution $T(t) = c e^{kt}$. Now, since heat doesn't grow exponentially with time, we can conclude that $k\leq 0$.

Now, solving the equation for $X(\mathbf{x})$ gives you a superposition of trig functions with wavenumber $k$ (if you use rectangular coordinates). The boundary conditions will determine what values of $k$ are allowed, $0\geq k_1\geq k_2\geq\ldots$ These form the eigenvalue spectrum of the problem. The overall solution will be $$u(\mathbf{x},t)=\sum_i c_i e^{k_i t} [\text{trigs} (\mathbf{x})]$$

Now, very small negative $k$ produce a rapid decay over time and high spatial frequencies: they decline fast from the initial state. The components of the sum that remains big longest are $k_1=0$ (if it exists) representing a constant  average, and the next one, which is the slowest decaying part. That eigenvalue is what sets the time constant for the approach to the steady state.

So the answer to the question is (kind of) that the timescale is $1/k_1$ where $k_1$ is the largest of the nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however isn't the timescale required in this solution still infinity to actually reach the stationary solution (instead of slowly approximating it)?

My question used the heat equation as an example but really it's about a more general case where a differential equation might reach a stationary solution in finite time.

Comment: You did mention the heat equation, and typically differential equations do not reach stationary states in finite time unless they have very particular forms. The above solution method is applicable for separable equations, which would give you answers.